# PHP geocaching API curl issues

Tags: php, api, curl, geocaching

I'm trying to access user information using the [Geocaching.com](http://geocaching.com) API service. Using the following [script](https://github.com/Surfoo/geocaching-api) I get the errors mentioned below:

If i use it 'straight out of the box' (on a live server) i get back the following message:

```
Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be         activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in /home/mrmemeco/public_html/geo/src/Geocaching/OAuth/OAuth.php on line 329

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '28' in /home/mrmemeco/public_html/geo/src/Geocaching/OAuth/OAuth.php:334 Stack trace: #0 /home/mrmemeco/public_html/geo/src/Geocaching/OAuth/OAuth.php(206): Geocaching\OAuth\OAuth->curl_request('http://staging....') #1 /home/mrmemeco/public_html/geo/index.php(50): Geocaching\OAuth\OAuth->getRequestToken() #2 {main} thrown in /home/mrmemeco/public_html/geo/src/Geocaching/OAuth/OAuth.php on line 334
```

If i use it in the same way but on a localhost is get back HTTP error: 0 and no data is returned.

I've done a bit of googling and i have checked that safe mode is off but I've had no joy still.

It's definitely not my API keys as they work perfectly on the live [demo](http://geocaching.vaguelibre.net/api/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because the configuration of your server doesn't allow cUrl to follow locations. There is more than one way to solve this:

- If you have access to your server's root you have to edit the php.ini file and set `safe_mode = false`
- Otherwise you can create an `.htaccess` file in the root of your site and put this inside `php_value safe_mode off` or...
- You can change the value of `safe_mode` in your PHP script adding this line at the `ini_set('safe_mode', false);`

I hope it helps

Comment: thanks for replying, i've tried all your suggestions and i'm still getting the same error

Comment: Ok, rather than altering that values maybe it would be better to simply disable the cUrl option `FOLLOWLOCATION`. Try editing the file `/src/Geocaching/OAuth/OAuth.php` and changing the line 328 to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);`, then see if the script is working

Comment: with FOLLOWLOCATION set to FALSE I get: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'couldn't connect to host' in. With FOLLOWLOCATION set to TRUE I get the same CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION warning as before and the same error message... Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'couldn't connect to host' in